# How does interest rates impact investment

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, financial-economics, behavioral-economics

How does a decrease in interest rates decrease investment rates? This is how I believe a liquidity trap works, not sure if it is correct.

Thank you

Comment: What definition of “investment rate” are you using? Investment in economics refers to capital expenditure. Do you mean “interest rate” of “rate of return”?

Comment: Investment rate as private expenditure.

Comment: what do you mean by "Investment rate as private expenditure"? Amount of private investment of total private expenditure? Please clarify

Comment: In that case, that’s not what a liquidity trap refers to. (Admittedly, a lot of people have mis-used the term, so there might be someone who says that.) The liquidity trap is a phenomenon in bond markets, where yields cannot get lower.

Comment: Total expenditure yes.